# sidebar widgets not appearing in my site

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 websites using same template.. BUT in one of my websites, sidebar not appearing at all.. (in sidebar, it already has some widgets, but dont know why they're not showing those widgets into my sidebar)

**here they're:**

```
http://certifiedwelderservices.com/  //sidebar not getting
http://deputy-inspector.com/
```

Iam not understanding why below code is empty: (i kepted 3 widgets inside that sidebar)

```
<div class="barsmall right" id="right_colum">
                            </div>
```

Sidebar itself not showing...

please kindly someone look into this.

Answer (score 0):

When developing the second site did you just copy the first complete site over?

Meaning, developer site A, then move the setup to site B and then have issues?

How did you transfer the site over and change the URL?  It could be that the theme or widgets use serialized PHP strings and are not taking the domain change correctly.

This search and replace tool is good if you know what you are doing with the WP database.
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: no, I didnt copied .. i just normally created both  sites, BUT iam not understanding why sidebar not appearing only in one site...